# I get an error after using `a2ensite MyDomain.com.conf` and running `service apache2 reload`

Tags: server, apache2

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS hosted on Linode.

What I want is to reload the apache2 after i used the `a2ensite MyDamain.com.conf`. But I get an error after I use `a2ensite MyDomain.com.conf` then reload apache2 `service apache2 reload`

The error after the command is

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I used `system status apache2.service`, I get these results :

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-11-29 10:44:42 EST; 29min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16126 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 15556 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16148 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─16165 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16168 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─16169 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Nov 29 10:44:41 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 10:44:41 hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 29 10:44:41 hostname apache2[16148]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 10:44:42 hostname apache2[16148]:  *
Nov 29 10:44:42 hostname systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Here's the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `journalctl -u apache2.service` output:

```
[Wed Nov 29 09:18:18.391354 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2603:tid 140612271839104] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 09:18:18.391428 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2603:tid 140612271839104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 09:19:16.891581 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2603:tid 140612271839104] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Nov 29 09:19:16.896943 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2603:tid 140612271839104] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 09:19:16.896954 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2603:tid 140612271839104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 10:42:59.573821 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2603:tid 140612271839104] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 29 10:43:48.125153 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16050:tid 140568317134720] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 10:43:48.125248 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16050:tid 140568317134720] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 10:44:40.835976 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16050:tid 140568317134720] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 29 10:44:41.915837 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16165:tid 140038324930432] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 10:44:41.915935 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16165:tid 140038324930432] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 14:40:22.055349 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16165:tid 140038324930432] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 29 14:41:33.755038 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 14:41:33.755125 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 14:41:38.205079 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Nov 29 14:41:38.210405 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 14:41:38.210417 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 14:42:24.424726 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Nov 29 14:42:24.429568 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 14:42:24.429577 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 14:51:13.673871 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20426:tid 139872130365312] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 29 14:51:14.736870 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20855:tid 140107096328064] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 14:51:14.736939 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20855:tid 140107096328064] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 14:51:20.681637 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20855:tid 140107096328064] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Nov 29 14:51:20.686725 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20855:tid 140107096328064] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 14:51:20.686735 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20855:tid 140107096328064] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 15:48:46.861157 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20855:tid 140107096328064] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 29 15:50:12.237275 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4423:tid 140346390390656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 15:50:12.237757 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4423:tid 140346390390656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 15:50:23.361181 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4423:tid 140346390390656] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Nov 29 15:50:23.366024 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4423:tid 140346390390656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 15:50:23.366032 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4423:tid 140346390390656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 15:54:31.116056 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4423:tid 140346390390656] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 29 16:22:54.524680 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5595:tid 140625337571200] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 16:22:54.524760 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5595:tid 140625337571200] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 29 16:23:08.498668 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5595:tid 140625337571200] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Nov 29 16:23:08.503243 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5595:tid 140625337571200] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 29 16:23:08.503252 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5595:tid 140625337571200] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

And:

```
root@hostname:~#   journalctl -u apache2.service
-- Logs begin at Wed 2017-11-29 15:48:57 EST, end at Thu 2017-11-30 08:17:40 EST. --
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]:  *
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]: Output of config test was:
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot acc
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname apache2[3475]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 29 15:48:58 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 29 15:50:00 hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]:  *
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]: Output of config test was:
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot acc
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname apache2[4328]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 29 15:50:01 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 29 15:50:12 hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 29 15:50:12 hostname apache2[4406]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 15:50:13 hostname apache2[4406]:  *
Nov 29 15:50:13 hostname systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:50:23 hostname systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:50:23 hostname apache2[4505]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 15:50:23 hostname apache2[4505]:  *
Nov 29 15:50:23 hostname systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]:  *
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]:  * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anyth
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]: Output of config test was:
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot acc
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname apache2[4599]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited
Nov 29 15:50:35 hostname systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname apache2[4621]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname apache2[4621]:  *
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname apache2[4621]:  * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anyth
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname apache2[4621]: Output of config test was:
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname apache2[4621]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot acc
Nov 29 15:53:52 hostname apache2[4621]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
```

Comment: Please provide us with apache error log.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 16.04 and not 64.04. Also, the output you posted seems to be truncated. Can you pipe the command to `cat` so all the output is printed `systemctl status apache2.service | cat`? But, judging by this truncated message `2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot acce` I suspect the Directory you have configured in the `MyDomain.com.conf` file does not exist or Apache does not have access to it. Content in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` would most likely be helpful as well.

Comment: Yeah it's 60.04, sorry for the typo

Comment: Also added the error.log to the thread

Comment: @cody-cortez I believe it is Ubuntu 16.04 (sixteen point zero four), not 60.04 (sixty point zero four). Both versions 60.04 and 64.04 are not yet released.

Comment: According to the logs you posted, it seems apache is in fact running. This is part which mentions it: `Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-11-29 10:44:42 EST; 29min ago`

Comment: @Dan Yes apache2 is running. But when I reload it, the error `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` shows up. 

I want to reload apache2 after i used the `a2ensite MyDamain.com.conf`

Comment: Did i provide enough info to solve this? I need this sorted out

Comment: The problem is that the logs you posted don't have any details anymore, while the first version of your had an error (which was truncated). Run the `reload` command again so you get an error, then run `systemctl status apache2.service | cat` so the error message shows in the output. Also, posting the content of `MyDamain.com.conf` may help as well. (replace sensitive data in that file if there are any, but don't delete the lines please)

Comment: @Dan i triggered the error again and updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, Just a typo at the target of `MyDomain.com.conf`

-_-